# Difference between the size of the original image decomposed by wavedec2 and reconstructed by waverec2

Tags: python, wavelet, pywt

I'm using Pywt to work with wavelet transform. I'm doing the decomposition to get the detail coefficients and then the reconstruction by now.

I invoke the wavedec2 function with this arguments: X (ndarray 125x125), w = 'sym4', n = 4

```
coeffs = pywt.wavedec2(x,w,n);
```

The problem is when i make the reconstruction, I'm wating for a ndarray of 125x125 but the result of this function is a ndarray of 126x126.

```
xc = pywt.waverec2(coeffs,w);
```

Why I have an extra row and column?